# Error while adding double values to a double array

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, double, locationmanager

I am trying to add the location values into a double array but it is giving me nullpointerexcetion. I request location updates like this

```
if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
                        if (!manager
                                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                            mylocation = manager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            location_checked = true;
                        } else {
                            manager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0,
                                    listener);
                            location_checked = true;
                        }
                    }
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                       5000,0, listener);
```

And then i set the incoming location values to myLocation

```
LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mylocation = location;

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};
```

and after that i try to add the values to a double array but it gives me error and crashes my app at this point

```
double[] locationData = new double[] {mylocation.getLatitude(),  
                                      mylocation.getLongitude() };
```

Comment: Obviously `mylocation` is `null`.  You haven't provided anywhere near enough information for us to guess why it isn't getting set.  Are you sure `onLocationChanged` has happened?

Comment: Possibly the listener doesn't get its first update before locationData is instantiated?

Comment: yes no listener did not get any update and i tried to send the data

Answer (score 0):

You should make it like this:

```
    @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lng = location.getLongitude();
    setlocationData(lat, lng);
  }
```

Because until the Location is set from LocationChanged, it is null.

It takes time till the LocationManager gets de GPS Signal.